# Mongoose Schema method - 'this.username' returning undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Within my applicaton, I have the following schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 4,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 1024
  },
})
```

I also have the following model:

```
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And finally I have a schema method:

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = () => {
  const token = jwt.sign({_id: this._id, username: this.username, email: this.email},'KEYTEST');
  console.log(this.username)
  return token;
}
```

I then run the following code in one of my API routes:

```
user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
})
await user.save();
  
const token = user.generateAuthToken();
res.send(token)
```

I then call this API route in my frontend, and on the server console, I expect the value of `this.username` to be printed to the console. Instead I get undefined. I get the same for `this._id` and `this.email`. Also, the **user object is successfully created** in mongodb and has the expected values for properties such as **_id**, **username** and **email**.

Does anyone know why I am getting undefined printed? Thanks.

Comment: A wild guess from me would be an issue with the `this` call, try giving the function a parameter and call the parameter.username etc. maybe that works

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum Hello This has worked thanks. However why does `this` not work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/2282634

Comment: You are creating arrow function to generateAuthToken, which don't have any context. if you create function using 'function' keyword, issue will be resolved.